# Diagnosing Visual Studio 2015 repeated crashing/restarting

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 and I have one project that habitually crashes/restarts about ever 10 minutes.  It doesn't happen with all my projects, it just seems to be one offending project.  What is the best way to analyze what is causing the crash?

Comment: Try running without any extensions enabled for a bit see if that makes a difference, then you can reintroduce until you find the culprit.  Just an idea, not guaranteed to work.  The initial Resharper was quite bad for 2015 for example, they did an update but I'm still not sure if it is 100%...

Comment: Tried installing the Resharper update.  Still getting crashes/restarts, tho VS seems to run a little longer before crashing. :(

Comment: Just updated to Resharper 9.2 and the crashing has stopped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a many MSVS compilers around ... but MSVS 2015 isn't one of them.

HOWEVER:

I think one or both of the following might help:

1. Start MSVS, Open your project, and go into Tools > Options >

   - Environment > Auto-recover: turn OFF (for troubleshooting)
   - Projects and Solutions: disable anything that looks "suspicious"
2. Try starting MSVS with the [/log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) parameter.

   Look here for more details: [Debugging a Visual Studio Crash](http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for many thanks!.  And am going to update Resharper too per recommendation of @Derek.

Comment: I can't get VS to start in dignostics mode or otherwise find the ActivityLog.xml

Comment: Additional suggestions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/02/24/troubleshooting-with-the-activity-log.aspx (for older MSVS), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165103.aspx (with `devenv /safemode` option), and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025133 (MSVS 2015 RC Fixed Bugs and Known Issues)

Comment: Thanks again.  I now got my paws on the activitylog.xml, hope i can figure out what is going on...

Comment: Strange thing is that VS does not seem to be logging any type of "error" even though logging was on during the most recent crash.

Comment: `Environment` > `Auto-recover` has nothing to do with auto-restarting Visual Studio after a crash. It is for auto-saving file modifications every N minutes. Also when VS crashes, it will not write anything to the log so the `/log` option is also all but useless for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I tried a whole bunch of stuff I saw online and only got frustration for a result. When I looked into the logs I discovered every time it crashed it threw a "Path too long" exception. I didn't, and still don't, know how or why that was happening, but the two were definitely correlated. In desperation I decided to try moving my code from the "H" (network) drive to the local ("C") drive. The problem went away. For what it's worth I thought I should post this. Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: This solution not working, some time VS 2015 ask for restart and debug.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply try : **devenv.exe /resetuserdata** instead of reinstalling the whole program, it worked for my case.

Comment: Can you at least provide on the steps on how to execute that?

Comment: I wrote my answer 2.5 years ago so you better say : 'Can you please provide some steps on how to execute it'

Comment: anyway, to execute it, you need to run the cmd from the folder where is located your deven.exe and execute this command **devenv.exe /resetuserdata** (For my case deven.exe is located on C > Program Files (x86) > Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 > Common 7 > IDE)

Answer (score 0):

After so many researches on google, i finally solved the same restart issue in my VS2015. The solution is that place the project soultion inside "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects". The project should not open in local.