# Visual Studio 2015 always restarting when debbuging my application (UWP) for mobile devices

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash, uwp, windows-10-universal, restart

I am trying to debug my application (UWP Windows 10) on my mobile phone with windows 10 mobile build 10.0.14372.0 but, when I try, visual studio crashes and restarts.

I need to debug my app on my mobile device. On my PC works fine.

I try this but without good results:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93852967-1b60-46f8-b0d2-2873f98422c3/visual-studio-crash-during-debugging?forum=netfxbcl
- Disable resharper.
- [Diagnosing Visual Studio 2015 repeated crashing/restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017857/diagnosing-visual-studio-2015-repeated-crashing-restarting)

Any ideas?

Comment: We would like to get in touch with you to know more about this. Can you send an email to debugger[at]microsoft[dot]com
Once we know the root cause and the solution, we'll post it here for the benefit of the community.